# Tooltip based on attribute using JQuery tooltip

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make the tooltip load an image based on an attribute from the element, however there are multiple elements with different images so I am attempting to load the image based on an attribute.
**HTML:**

```
<a class="item" href="#" title="" image="images/1.png">image 1.</a> 
</br> 
<a class="item" href="#" title="" image="images/1.png">image 1.</a>
```

**JS:**

```
$(".item" ).tooltip({ content:'<img src="somehow get image from image attribute if possible?" />' });
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vvVwD/327/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".item" ).each(function() {
    $(this).tooltip({ content:'<img src="'+this.getAttribute('image')+'" />' });
});
```

Using a data attribute, as in data-image, would be more appropriate, and more valid

```
<a class="item" href="#" title="" data-image="images/1.png">image 1.</a>
```

and then

```
$(".item" ).each(function() {
    $(this).tooltip({ content:'<img src="'+ $(this).data('image') +'" />' });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vvVwD/328/)***

```
$(".item").tooltip({
    content: function () {
        return $(this).attr('image');
    }
});
```

If you need an image, just wrap the return value with image tags like below.

```
return '<img src="' + $(this).attr("image") + '">';
```